# Offline iOS7 web app: doesn't update manifest

Tags: ipad, caching, ios7, offline

I have written a web app for offline usage on iOS7 safari and, while it does download the files in the manifest for offline usage, it never updates cached files when the manifest changes.

I have a php script that loops through files in a directory and creates a `cache.appcache` file. It also adds a comment that is a md5 of the files so that each time a file changes, the `cache.appcache` file will update.

This works fine on desktop chrome and the app cache update is triggered. However, on the iPad it never tries to update the cache: I have to clear the device's cache manually to get the updated app.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I don't get this... please elaborate and add code

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/#trigger-refresh

Updates in the cache.manifest file are supposed to trigger cache updates. In my app this doesn't happen on the iPad but does on the deskop.

Answer (score 0):

http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/#trigger-refresh

Updates in the cache.manifest file are supposed to trigger cache updates. This was happening on desktop browsers but not on the iPad.

For future reference this appeared to be caused by a combination of iOS 'web app' mode and the HTTP Auth password I had on the page. It seems that this combination prevented the cache update check because it worked fine in regular iOS safari but only worked in both after I removed the password.